# Cannot get header property from HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Any

Tags: azure, httpcontext

I am working on API controller, it can get the header property in the filter, but not able to get the header property in controller, it uses same code in filter and in the controller.

```
string applicationId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Any(x => x.ToUpper().Equals(Constants.ApplicationId.ToUpper())) ?HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.GetValues(Constants.ApplicationId).FirstOrDefault() : string.Empty;
```

For the APIs which do not use filter, we can get header property in controller.

I tested with integrated/classic pipeline mode in my local with filter, there is no problem, but there is problem in the Web Role in  China Azure Cloud. we are using .Net4.5

Comment: Added code block

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext can only be accessed once, afterward it is unavailable,
if you need to get multiple properties from HttpContext,
you must access them together.

**for example**,

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Any(...);
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Any(...);
```

if you put some other code between the two lines, the second HttpContext will be unavailable.
is this a defect?